# Rotate the uri image 90 degrees in the SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to use the definition code to solve this problem.The following code works perfectly in the VS,But there was some problem with SSRS.

```
Public Function Convert(url As String) As Byte()
    Try
       Dim wr As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
       Dim res As System.Net.WebResponse = wr.GetResponse
       Dim bmp As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(res.GetResponseStream)
       Dim bitmapData As Byte() = Nothing
       Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
            bitmapData = ms.ToArray()
       End Using
       Return ms.ToArray()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

I think the reason for the problem is insufficient permissions. I searched for relevant solutions on the Internet, but I got nothing.I shall be grateful to anyone who can help me.
[image: Exception Message]

Comment: Do you mean with "definition code" the code section in ssrs under the report properties?

Comment: @Strawberryshrub Yes.That's what I want to say

Comment: Maybe this helps https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c82c6357-c79a-4434-8f4d-5d66fe0dfff1/use-systemdrawingimaging-in-custom-report-code-without-using-a-custom-assembly?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: @Strawberryshrub According to the information you provided, I reopened the report editor after changing the configuration, and the expected effect was successfully achieved. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I will post it as answer, that you can mark it as solution for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge, to use reference in the report, we need to grant the permission for assembly. For detail information, please refer to the following steps:

1. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies \RSpreviewPolicy.config`.
2. Give `FullTrust` for `Report_Expressions_Default_Permissions`
3. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rssrvpolicy.config`
4. Give `FullTrust` for `Report_Expressions_Default_Permissions`

And here is the original article: [Original article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c82c6357-c79a-4434-8f4d-5d66fe0dfff1/use-systemdrawingimaging-in-custom-report-code-without-using-a-custom-assembly?forum=sqlreportingservices)